# Saving the response of a http request in Swift

Tags: json, swift, http

I'm trying to make a http request in Swift, get a JSON as a response and save it (to get the needed data out of it and present it in some way on the screen)

I'm making a request like this

```
func makeRequest(base: String, completionHandler: (JSON?, ErrorType?) -> Void){
    do {
        let opt = try HTTP.GET(baseUrl + "?base=" + base)
        opt.start { response in
            if let err = response.error {
                completionHandler(nil, err)
                return                }
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data: response.data)
                completionHandler(json, nil)
                return
            }
            catch {
                completionHandler(nil, nil)
                return
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}
```

I call the "makeRequest" function like this

```
func convert(value:Double, startCurrency:Currency, targetCurrency:Currency) -> (converted: Double, endCurrency: Currency) {

    let api = ApiManager()
    api.makeRequest(firstType, completionHandler: { (json:JSON?, error:ErrorType?) in
         // how to save the JSON in here?
    })

    //calculate the correct value using the data from the json and return it
    return (0.0, targetCurrency)
}
```

I'm new to Swift and I'm not really sure how to store the variable "json" after I get it from "api.makeRequest" ...
Everything I do with it in the "closure" stays there (like it should)...
How do I store it for the function "convert" to return it?

Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: If you want to simply handle your value, you can just write a new function that takes your **json** object from your completion handler. Otherwise you can create a dicitonary of objects from your json and store it in NSUserDefaults or CoreData. Alternatively, can also Cache the value for later use.

Answer (score 0):

One check out https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. Second do you want to store the data in CoreData or some form of database? If not you can just post it to a text field right away.

Example of SwiftyJSON:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
  if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
  MytextLabel1.text = userName // set text field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks vey good, you just need to do the last step. You have two choices for this. The easiest (and recommended) way would be the following:

```
func convert(value:Double, startCurrency:Currency, targetCurrency:Currency, cb: ((Double, Currency) -> Void) {
    let api = ApiManager()
    api.makeRequest(firstType, completionHandler: { (json:JSON?, error:ErrorType?) in
         // handle the error?
         // parse your JSON
         cb(amount, currency)
    })
}
```

To get the data out of *that* callback, here's an example. I'm assuming you are trying to present the data in a `UILabel`, and that you are calling `convert:` from your `UIViewController` subclass.

```
// Your code
convert(12, /* whatever currency */) {
  (amount, currency) in
  displayLabel.text = "\(amount)"
}
// More of your code
```

Comment: Why are you saying that it is synchronous? `HTTP` (SwiftHTTP) is an asynchronous library. Anyway, your approach to keep the main thread blocked is wrong. iOS can kill the application that freezes for too long the main thread.

Comment: @LucaD the HTTP callback isn't, synchronous, but the call to `convert` is. If it is **absolutely vital** that that call remains synchronous, I gave a solution. I am fully aware that it is extremely dangerous, however, which is why I added the warnings to it.

Comment: the correct way here is to use a `void` type for `convert` function. And use a `closure` or `delegation` to handle the end of the operation

Comment: Which is exactly what I did in the first half of my answer.

Comment: @LucaD I edited my answer to remove the dangerous code and clarify the first half.